# Issue while Timing Selection Sort

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, time, clock, c++-chrono

I had to write a program to implement Selection Sort and display the time elapsed for the process. But when I run the code on VSCode, I keep getting the duration as 0. Whereas on an online compiler, it shows the actual duration. I can't seem to figure out why. Please help.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std;

int flag=0;

void selectionSort(int a[],int n)
{
    int i,j,min;
    for(i=0;i<=n-2;i++)
    {
        min=i;
        for(j=i+1;j<=n-1;j++)
        {
            flag+=1;
            if(a[j]<a[min])
            {
                min=j;
            }
        }
        swap(a[min],a[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the number of elements to be sorted"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];
    cout<<"Enter the elements to be sorted"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }   
    auto start=chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    selectionSort(a,n);
    auto end=chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout<<"The elements after being sorted are"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"\nThe time complexity is O("<<flag<<")"<<endl;
    auto duration=duration_cast<nanoseconds>(end-start);
    cout<<"Duration is: "<<duration.count()<<" ns"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[This is the output on VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk085.png)

Comment: So you enter, what? 3 numbers? 50? 100? You cant enter enough numbers to make a difference on a modern machine. If you want to measure the timings of your sorting, then you should throw several hundred thousands or more at it. Do a few runs and average it.

Comment: Right. But then how is it I get the duration for 5 elements on an online compiler?

Comment: Maybe the machine is much slower? More users are hitting hit, so your process doesn't get enough time? a difference of 5 or 0 nanonseconds is not really significant. You need to run multiple iterations to get a feeling for the variation. Also you need to measure on the machine you actually intend to run it, if you want to improve performance for a given problem.

Comment: Microsoft implementation of `<chrono>` is not so great (you can google different issues if you are interested). Even though sorting 5 elements should be done very fast on modern machines, I imagine you still should have some non-zero value of elapsed time, if only because of function invocation. You can see https://godbolt.org/z/9vse6vWYb that it actually measures around 100ns.

Comment: @pptaszni Thank you very much :) Is there any way to fix it and be able to get a non-zero time duration on VSCode?

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by "The time complexity is (...)"? The complexity of your algorithm is O(n^2)

Comment: Yes, do as suggested in other comments. Either increase the number of elements in the array (you can use random generator to populate it, instead of `std::cin`), or run the sorting algorithm multiple (like 10^6) times.

Comment: @pptaszni Oh yes. About the time complexity. I didn't really understand why they wanted it that way either. But this is for an assignment and it was asked that the time complexity should be formatted that way with n^2 replaced by the number of times swapping occurs. So I'm just keeping it the way they asked :/

Comment: If you need the number of swaps, then your question is wrong. How do you determine how often a swap happened from the time?

Comment: @Devolus Oh Yes. I'm so sorry. I meant the number of times a comparison occurs between 2 elements. My bad . Sorry

Comment: use `flag` to determine is you have to swap, only set `flag` if you have to change `min`